# Powershell activesync statistics script issue

Tags: powershell

I am trying to generate a csv report for our HR team that will list:

- display name
- primary smtp address
- samaccountname
- department
- title
- office
- manager
- account status (enabled,disabled)
- Device Model
- DeviceOS
- LastSyncAttemptTime

My script is as follows:

```
$users = get-aduser -Filter * `
    -SearchBase "ou=hr,ou=burbank,ou=corp,dc=corp,dc=castandcrew,dc=com" `
    -Properties * | 
    select DisplayName,EmailAddress,samAccountName,Department,Title,Office,Manager,Enabled

 "DisplayName;EmailAddress;samAccountName;Department;Title;Office;Manager;Enabled;DeviceModel;DeviceOS;LastSyncAttemptTime"

foreach ($u in $users) {
    $a = Get-MobileDeviceStatistics -Mailbox $u.EmailAddress | 
        select DeviceModel,DeviceOS,LastSyncAttemptTime

    "{0};{1};{2};{3};{4};{5};{6};{7};{8};{9};" -f
        $u.DisplayName, $u.EmailAddress, $u.samAccountName, $u.Department, $u.Title, $u.Office, $u.Manager, $u.Enabled, $a.DeviceModel, $a.DeviceOS, $a.LastSyncAttemptTime
}
```

Seems to work ok, except some user info is not pulled as shown below (see Lynn Johnson):

```
Lynn Johnson;Lynn.Johnson@castandcrew.com;ljohnson;Human Resources;SVP, Human Resources;Burbank;CN=Eric Belcher,OU=Users,OU=Restricted,OU=Burbank,OU=Corp,DC=CORP,DC=CASTANDCREW,DC=COM;True;System.Object[];System.Object[];
Renee Thurau;Renee.Thurau@castandcrew.com;rthurau;Human Resources;Executive Asisstant to SVP, Human Resources;Burbank;CN=Lynn Johnson,OU=Users,OU=HR,OU=Burbank,OU=Corp,DC=CORP,DC=CASTANDCREW,DC=COM;True;iPhone8C1;iOS 10.3.3 14G60;
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The root of your problem is that Lynn Johnson has multiple devices and your code assumes that `Get-MobileDeviceStatistics` will only return a single result.

Because Lynn's query returns multiple results, the reference you made to `$a.DeviceModel` and such are object arrays (likely strings). You need to account for that in some way depending on your business requirements. I'm guessing the most logical for someone consuming the CSV would be to have a record per-device. So if Lynn has 3 devices, she would have 3 rows in the CSV.  But you could also just try to join the elements of the array into a single combined column value. Or you could choose to only report on the first device, etc.

There are a few other suggestions I have for your script as well.

- Don't use `-Properties *` in your `Get-ADUser` query. It's wasteful in terms of processing time and bandwidth. You already know what properties you want. So just write them out in the script.
- Don't try to manually format the CSV output. Let Powershell's native `Export-CSV` cmdlet do the work for you. It has a `-Delimiter` parameter so you can still use a semicolon if you don't like the comma default.

Comment: Yes. A record per device. What would the best way to do this? Can you pipe to export-csv from a foreach loop?

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to Ryan, but I like to build an object that includes what you want and then use that to create an array that has all of your data. Then you can export it or work with it as desired.

- Added explicit properties to your queries
- Handled the duplicate mobile devices with a ForEach loop
- Used the new `$output` variable to utilize Export-CSV with the `-Delimtter ';'` option

script code:

```
$users = get-aduser -Filter * `
    -SearchBase "ou=hr,ou=burbank,ou=corp,dc=corp,dc=castandcrew,dc=com" `
    -Properties DisplayName,EmailAddress,Department,Title,Office,Manager 

# Set up output as an empty array 
$output = @()

foreach ($u in $users) {
    # Get Statistics for that user, making an explicit array
    $Stats = @(Get-MobileDeviceStatistics -Mailbox $u.EmailAddress)

    $Stats | ForEach-Object {
        # Create an anonomous object with the properties we want
        $current = "" | Select-Object "DisplayName","EmailAddress","samAccountName","Department","Title","Office","Manager","Enabled","DeviceModel","DeviceOS","LastSyncAttemptTime" 
        $current.DisplayName = $u.DisplayName
        $current.EmailAddress =$u.EmailAddress
        $current.samAccountName =$u.samAccountName
        $current.Department = $u.Department
        $current.Title = $u.Title
        $current.Office = $u.Office
        $current.Manager = $u.Manager
        $current.Enabled = $u.Enabled
        $current.DeviceModel =  $_.DeviceModel
        $current.DeviceOS = $_.DeviceOS
        $current.LastSyncAttemptTime = $_.LastSyncAttemptTime

        # Add the current object to the output for later 
        $output += $current
    }
}

$output | Export-CSV -Path C:\report.csv -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation -NoClobber
```

Comment: This is perfect. However, the output is not being delimited properly. It's running all together.

Comment: When opening with what? It looks fine to me:
`"DisplayName";"EmailAddress";"samAccountName";"Department";"Title";"Office";"Manager";"Enabled";"DeviceModel";"DeviceOS";"LastSyncAttemptTime"`